# Cheap colour laser printer + scanner for infrequent home use

Tags: printer, scanner

I am looking to replace my inkjet and believe that a laser printer would be cheaper I the long run. I occasionally need colour printing, although not too often. I also need to be able to scan documents.

I am currently based in Britain. What can you recommend, not just on purchase price, but also on running costs? E.g something that accepts non-manufacturer toner cartridges.

A4 is sufficient; nothing larger needed. I don;t care about the interface, whether USB, WiFi, etc

Hmmmm, I suppose that I could settle for B&W and just seek out an internet cafe when I need colour. It would be less convenient, but cheaper.

---

[Update] I probably print 10, max 20 pages per month

Comment: What's your print usage, roughly. 10 sheets a day or 2 a month? I'm closer to the latter most times. About 15 years ago I spent a couple of hundred on at the time the cheapest, smallest multifunction colour laser, a Samsung. The toner lasted 10 years, after which I decided it would be more economical [+they tend to stop making drivers, so it no longer integrates properly] to just buy a new machine than refill it. I bought a HP MFP M477, which after another 5 years still has most of the toner left [though these days your first toner cartridges are supplied only half full… watch out for that.]

Comment: Since I bought the first laser I've spent considerably less on machines + toner than I used to spend on ink alone.